# It's possible to share a managed InApp billing purchase between applications

Tags: google-play, in-app-billing

It's possible to share a managed InApp billing purchase between applications?

Or in other words:
If I've a managed item in application **A** can I check from application **B** if it's purchased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is natively supported by Google Play.

If both apps are installed on a device, then your app B could call app A and ask whether an item is purchased. You can do this via Intents or app A could implement a service or a content provider and app B could call it to check the status of a managed purchase.